# A good way to take care of Pelargonium

Tags: watering, plant-care

How often should they be watered?  How much? Any parts that need cutting off? I have one potted plant which is pretty grown. And has pink flowers.

Thanks!

Comment: Wonderful plants but we need to know if yours is evergreen or an annual (most likely an annual)...the best thing you could do is get those flowers off that plant as soon as you can stomach taking flowers off.  At least the older flowers!  Don't allow this plant to make seed.  Cut anything off that isn't healthy, send PICTURES!  Tell us your basic maintenance style...

Comment: Water only when the soil has dried out enough to make your pot and plant feel lighter.  Water deeply and allow to dry out before watering again.  Watch your plant, if it looks wilted check the dryness of your soil and water deeply. Be aware of that wilted look, don't want plants to get wilted too often!!  Recognize the heft of the pot when your plant needs water.  Keep your saucer emptied!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelargoniums are very low maintenance, drought resistant, and don't need much water. You can water them when the soil is dry to the touch.

You can remove dead flowers, dead branches and dead leaves, if any.

If the plant is fully grown, you can propagate the plant by simply using stem cuttings, and thus trim your plant down.

Alternately, you can re-pot the plant in a larger pot.